# Golang https setting trouble

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, https

I'm having trouble setting up https on AWS:

I get a certificate from letsencrypt by using certbot command on my server:

```
./certbot-auto certonly --standalone -d go.minmacro.com --debug --agree-tos
```

and I got success message:

Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at:

> /etc/letsencrypt/live/go.minmacro.com/fullchain.pem

Your key file has been saved at:

> /etc/letsencrypt/live/go.minmacro.com/privkey.pem

in my go code i'm using:

```
err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(":443 ", "/etc/letsencrypt/live/go.minmacro.com/fullchain.pem", "/etc/letsencrypt/live/go.minmacro.com/privkey.pem", r)

fmt.Println(err)
```

when i run this code, go thrown an error:

> listen tcp: address tcp/443 : unknown port

even though i've already added https to my sercurity group

Could anyone give me a suggestion? I've been struggle with this trouble for few days

Comment: There's a space in your address string.  Should be ":443".

Comment: Really thanks! You save my day! I can't believe it cause by a simple mistake like that :))